# On text-input keypress I want to show validation error without any plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

On text-input keypress I want to show validation error without any plugin.
I am trying to code a generic jQuery function which I could use in any page.
The error pop-up should be dynamic.

```
function checkno(txt,e) {

    $(txt).keypress(function (e) {
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            if (!document.getElementById('spanmsg')) {
                $(txt).after("<span id='spanmsg'  class='fixed'>This is wrong input</span>")                    
                $('#spanmsg').show(0).delay("500").hide(0);
                txt.value = '';
            }
            else {                    
                $('#spanmsg').show(0).delay("500").hide(0);
                txt.value = '';
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the `#spanmsg` show up?

Comment: i want to  validate input on keypress and show error message as tooltip error . I am looking for generic solution for overall application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put whole code below,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please Rate if it helps</title>
    <!-- PUT A PATH OF JQUERY LIBRARY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            $("#txt").keypress(function (e) {
                //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                    if (!$(txt).next().hasClass("spanmsg")) {
                        var error = $("<div class='spanmsg'>This is wrong input</div>");
                        $(txt).after(error);
                        $(error).css({
                            top: ($(txt).position().top + 1) + "px",
                            left: ($(txt).position().left + 1) + "px",
                            width: $(txt).width() + "px",
                            height: $(txt).height() + "px"
                        });
                    }
                    $(this).next().show(0).delay("500").delay(500, function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    this.value = '';
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .spanmsg {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
</body>
</html>
```

Rate if it helps you...

Comment: it does not go into if block ,it just exist from if block.......in firebug is how returnvalue undefined

Comment: It's my pleasure. Vote if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead try keyup method as :

```
$(theElement).keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, function(str) { alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use only numbers.'); return ''; } ) );
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks..  but instead of alert i want to insert dynamic div to page and trigger that div as error bubble  and just fadeout.

Comment: Use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add your error to the html and later [fadeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

just using your code updated to this, **without additional frameworks**. Run it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3znx3my8/8/).

```
function checkno(txt,e) {

        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            if (!document.getElementById('spanmsg')) {
                $(txt).after("<span id='spanmsg'  class='fixed'>This is wrong input</span>")                    
                $('#spanmsg').show(0).delay("500").hide(0);
                txt.value = '';
            }
            else {                    
                $('#spanmsg').show(0).delay("500").hide(0);
                txt.value = '';
            }
            return false;
        }
}

$('#txt').keyup(function (e) {
    checkno(this,e);
});
```

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/3znx3my8/1  how did you add an alert to break it? apply link to your code please.

Comment: so what does not work here? your code erase input value on every letter usage, span msg appears and disappears.

Comment: are you able to on jsfiddle its not working ,i am  able type the letters and nothing happens

Comment: That's strange. What browser do you use? When i'm type letter message appears at right from input. I found an issue with firefox but safari and chrome works fine.

Comment: actually not working on mozila ,but works in chrome thanks

Comment: i found the solution that makes working in safari, chrome, firefox. i will update my answer