# how to validate a field entry as user still enters the value into a field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to validate a form for login and registration. As I had seen in some websites... as im entering my username or email it validates ontime even while im still on that field.

I did the validation with "onblur" event. I guess it would be "onkeypress" to get what i want. But as i change that onblur () to onkeypress() by keeping as the event handler code same, it results some heck. Im not even able to enter a key into field.

I changed onblur="return validUser ();" to onkeypress="return valodUser ();"

How to validate as i am entering data into field.

The event handling function validUser() is as follows:

```
function validUser(){
    var x=document.getElementById("userId").value;
    var userId_error=document.getElementById("userId_error");
    var userReg=/^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*/;

    if(x.length==0||x==null){
        document.getElementById("userId").style.border="2px solid red";
        document.getElementById("userId").style.backgroundColor="eceb8f";
        userId_error.innerHTML="Please enter Username.";
        document.getElementById("userId").focus();
        return false;
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("userId").style.border="1px solid #fff";
        userId_error.innerHTML="";
    }

    if(!userReg.test(x)){
        document.getElementById("userId").style.border="2px solid red";
        userId_error.innerHTML=" Please.   enter valid Username! (eg:Ram24,Jhon_s)";
        return false;
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("userId").style.border="1px solid #fff";
        userId_error.innerHTML="";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By just changing `onblur` to `onkeypress`, you are preventing the default action of the event by returning false if there is validation error and hence you are not able to enter anything.

On those websites, you would have noticed that they show error on the right of input field and don't stop you from entering invalid data. You have to implement something similar.

Comment: Can u please suggest a solution..?

Comment: try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103443/on-text-input-keypress-i-want-to-show-validation-error-without-any-plugin